# Zend : Block Access via URL

Tags: session, zend-framework, authentication, acl

I have in my first ZF1 application two controllers : AuthController et ProductController.
My code for the authentication work perfectly by using Zend_Auth.

But the user still can access in the application in the browser without authentication. For example if the user enter :

```
http://localhost/apptest/public/product/action
```

he can access directly. Must I use Zend_Session or Zend_Acl to block access if the user is not login?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Auth` is concerned only with authentication and not with authorization. Authentication is loosely defined as determining whether an entity actually is what it purports to be (i.e., identification), based on some set of credentials. Authorization, the process of deciding whether to allow an entity access to, or to perform operations upon, other entities is outside the scope of `Zend_Auth`. For more information about authorization and access control with Zend Framework, please see [`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html).